# DOS Batch copy over multiple files

Tags: batch-file, copy, dos, overwrite

This may be an unusual request, but I have a template ini file that I want to use to overwrite a bunch of ini files in a certain folder.  Something like

```
copy /b/v/y template.ini *gui_settings.ini
```

or

```
copy /b/v/y template.ini < dir *gui_settings.ini /b
```

This does not work.

I even tried

```
dir *gui_settings.ini /b >files.list
copy /b/v/y template.ini < files.list
```

...but no dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for %%a in ("*gui_settings.ini") do type "template.ini" > "%%a"
```

For each `*gui_settings.ini` file found, type the template into the file

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*gui_settings.ini) do (

    copy /b /y /v "%%~fa"+template.ini ~.ini
    copy /y /b /v ~.ini "%%~fa"
)
del /q /f ~.ini
```